# Set security descriptor for windows server process

Tags: security, access-control-list, windows-service

I would like to add a new DACL entry to the security-descriptor of windows service *process*. `sc sdset` allows to set permissions on the service for actions like start/stop/pause, but I want to set permissions on the process itself (create thread, terminate, dup handle, etc...).

How can I achieve this from the commandline with permanent effect?

For playing around I can use ProcessExplorer, but its effect only lasts until the service is restarted, and it's not scripted.

I could also modify the security-descriptor inside the service (with `SetSecurityInfo` winapi). But I see this as a "static" configuration that is set at service registration time, and not a "dynamic" one that is set during service runtime.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to tell Windows that you want your service process, or any other process for that matter, to always be given a non-standard security descriptor.  There would be no obvious sensible use for this functionality, and Microsoft generally try to avoid adding useless functionality.

Perhaps you have some edge case (though I can't imagine what it might be) but if so, you will need to make the necessary changes to the process security descriptor from the process itself during initialization.

Comment: The security descriptor is standard parameter when creating files or kernel objects with windows API's (CreateFIle, CreateProcess,CreatePipe, etc...). I assumed this information could also be provided for a service process as well.